# The Eq instance of a Key with mpsGeneric enabled seems strange

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
module Main
  where

import           Database.Persist.Sql
import           Database.Persist.TH

share
    [mkPersist
        sqlSettings
            { mpsGeneric = True
            , mpsPrefixFields = False
            , mpsEntityJSON = Just EntityJSON
                                { entityToJSON = 'keyValueEntityToJSON
                                , entityFromJSON = 'keyValueEntityFromJSON
                                }
            , mpsGenerateLenses = False
            }
    , mkMigrate "abc"]
    [persistLowerCase|
Test
    a String
|]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ (toSqlKey 1 :: TestId) /= (toSqlKey 1 :: TestId)
    print $ (toSqlKey 1 :: TestId) == (toSqlKey 1 :: TestId)

    print $ (toSqlKey 1 :: TestId) /= (toSqlKey 2 :: TestId)
    print $ (toSqlKey 1 :: TestId) == (toSqlKey 2 :: TestId)
```

In this haskell program, I enable the mpsGeneric switch, and the result of this program is:

```
True
True
False
False
```

If disable mpsGeneric, the result is:

```
True
False
False
True
```

It seems that, the Eq instance the above one is broken.
I test the program with

```
persistent of version 2.2.4.1
persistent-template of version 2.1.6
```

**This "feature" kills me a whole afternoon**, when I run the follow code:

```
filter (/= someKey) [key1, key2, key3]
```

Comment: Reproduced with persistent-2.2.2.1. Looks like the it happens http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.16/persistent-template-2.1.8/src/Database-Persist-TH.html#mkEntity in `addSyn`. If mpsGeneric is False this will be `id` and it works as expected. I think the bad deriving of Eq happens here http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-5.16/persistent-2.2.4.1/src/Database-Persist-Class-PersistEntity.html#Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. It is reported on github now: https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/issues/560